# Power Bi - How to generate report

Tags: powerbi

Hello good day to all out there
I'm new to power bi and i want to generate a report that will show me the most occurring entity in a bi report. 
Lamin 23,Musa 61,Ebrima 71
I want a report that will display Ebrima because Ebrima is the most occurring name in the system. Thank You.

Comment: This impossible to answer unless you provide more relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Measure using the CONCATENATEX ... TOPN ... pattern to achieve this.  Here's an example:

```
Top Name = CONCATENATEX( TOPN( 1 , Table1 , Table1[Occurences] , DESC ) , Table1[Name] )
```

There is Top N filtering functionality e.g. in the Visual level Filters, but the implementation was effectively broken last year and has not been repaired.

http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Top-N-after-Filtering/idi-p/186922